# How to get the build number in the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In the DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml workflow template to get the build number you just did:

`BuildDetail.BuildNumber` but this isn't available in the `12 template. How can I achieve the same result?

**Note:** I see there's a `GetBuildDetail` member that comes up in intellisense, but like everything else in these templates if there is an ounce of documentation, I can't find it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.getbuilddetail.aspx is of no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are available in Environment Variables now.  There is a Workflow Activity GetEnvironmentVariable you can use.  For Name property specify: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.BuildNumber

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. Do you know of a good place to learn more about the tfs workflows?

Comment: The workflow in TFS 2013 is significantly simpler than in 2012.  I've found just exploring the workflow for 20 mins is the best way to understand how it works.

Comment: I agree, I had the 11 and 12 templates open side by side and the 12 is much easier to digest.